# Whitelist emails for sign up activity in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am creating an app that lets users create an account with an email and password. I want users with only a particular email domain to be able to be authenticated and create an account. How do I do this using firebase Realtime database rules?

This is what i am trying and it is not working

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email.endswith('mintz.com')",
    ".write": "auth.token.email.endswith('mintz.com')",
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set rules to **auth** just for **realtime database** and **storage**

Comment: Alternatively , you can do it in your client code. Where you're validating the email anyway.